# apache not serving index.html unless specified

Tags: apache2.4

Im new to setting up apache - the site works fine on localhost but when I access it from the LAN it does now display the index.html file - instead the browser says:

This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.

Ive tried editing the apache2.conf file but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

I think you made another mistake. When you are on a different Computer on you network, the Apache server is not available on http://localhost/ but on the domain name or IP of the Apache Server.

The browser tries to open a connection to your client computer. But its not on localhost.